# how to customize the BindingNavigator used when dragging a data source onto form

Tags: winforms, data-binding, bindingnavigator

In Visual Studio 2013, when I pick "DataGridView" for a list-typed data source and drag the data source onto the design surface of a form, I get my DataGridView and a BindingNavigator, which is wonderful. Now, I can customize the choice of my control and use a custom control, instead of the DataGridView, which is also great. My question now is -- how can I inject my own subclass of BindingNavigator to be generated by that drag operation?

Thanks!

Oh. Similar question about when I drag my data source in as "Details". How do I inject my custom Labels? (I've got the custom textboxes and things, all right.)

Comment: What kind of customization do you need for labels an binding navigator?

Comment: @Reza: Add some functionality: e.g., `CustomLabel : Label, ICustomFunctionality {public ICustomFunctionality.DoSomething(){...}}`. Then I traverse the tree, sending the DoSomething message to those controls which understand it. For the navigator, I would like to add some buttons of my own and, hopefully, save it as a UserControl.